# PHP/MYSQL/JSON: Simplify JSON for API

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi I am trying to create an API that converts a results array from a database call into json that can be easily parsed.

Using the simple command `json_encode`, my JSON is a complicated, verbose mess of nested objects and arrays that is proving hard to parse on the other end.

Can anyone suggest a way to pare this down to the key information that should be provided: userid, long comment (lcom) and short comment (shcom) and how to send this as an API?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Here is the current JSON output produced from the following query and code:

```
$sql = "SELECT userid,shcom,lcom FROM comments WHERE userid = 1 LIMIT 4";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
$comments = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$comments[] = array('row'=>$row);
 } 
echo json_encode(array('comments'=>$comments));

Json output:
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "row": {
                "0": "1",
                "userid": "1",
                "1": "hello",
                "shcom": "hello",
                "2": "hellothere",
                "lcom”: "hellothere"
            }
        },
        {
            "row": {
                "0": "1",
                "userid": "1",
                “1”: ”agreed”,
                "shcom”: ”agreed”,
                “2”: ”agreedforonce”,
                "lcom”: ”agreedforonce”
            }
        },
        {
            "row": {
                "0": "1",
                "userid": "1",
                "1": "gohome",
                "shcom”: ”gohome“,
                “2”: ”gohomenow”,
                "lcom: ”gohomenow”
            }
        },
        {
            "row": {
                "0": "1",
                "userid": "1",
                "1": "getout”,
                "shcom”: ”getout”,
                “2”: ”getoutofhere”,
                "lcom: ”getoutofhere”
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The actual api just spills out without any word wrap. I inserted the newlines to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `mysqli` rather than `mysql` since `mysql` is deprecated. Regardless, the problems in your code are happening because of two reasons. One, `mysql_fetch_array` does not produce the results you are expecting. Two, in your iteration you are not extracting the answers the right way. To resolve, use `mysq_fetch_assoc` and push only each `$row` to your final array.

Replace this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $comments[] = array('row'=>$row);
}
```

to this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $comments[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: That worked.  To be clear, as I am fuzzy on terminology, is it correct to call the output [{"userid":"1","shcom":"hello","lcom":"hello there"},{...},{...}] a JSON object consisting of an array of dictionaries? or just an object consisting of an array?

Comment: Your result outputs a **string in JSON format**. You can then transform that string into a JSON object in Javascript or an array in PHP.